# How to search for # in Azure Search

Tags: elasticsearch, azure-cognitive-search

Hi I have a string field which has an nGram analyzer.

And our query goes like this.

```
$count=true&queryType=full&searchFields=name&searchMode=any&$skip=0&$top=50&search=/(.*)Site#12(.*)/
```

The test we are searching for has `Site#123`

The above query will work with all other alpha numeric charecters except #. Any idea how could I make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the standard tokenizer, the ‘#’ character was removed from indexed documents as it’s considered a separator. For indexing, you can either use a different tokenizer, such as the whitespace tokenizer, or replace the ‘#’ character with another character such as ‘_’ with the mapping character filter (underscore ‘_’ is not considered a separator). You can test the analyzer behavior using the Analyze API : https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/test-analyzer.

It’s important to know that the query terms of regex queries are not analyzed. This means that the ‘#’ character won’t be removed by the analyzer from the regex expression. You can learn more about query processing in Azure Search here: [How full text search works in Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture)

Comment: I could able to get it done by escaping the # .. WIth '\\'

Answer (score 0):

Your string is being tokenized by spaces and punctuation like `#`. If you want to search for `#` and other punctuation characters, you could consider tokenzing only by whitespace. Or perhaps do not apply any tokenization at all and treat a whole string as a single token.